# What is the benefit of Cookie over server side storage?

Tags: http, cookies

By server side storage I mean database or some kind of persistent cache system instead of session. 
Usually we store some user specific data in the client side using cookie, which will be sent to server during later requests. However, it's possible that we store these data in server side storage.

First, it will save a lot of bandwidth while using some server storage. Generally bandwidth is much more expensive than memories and hard disks.

Second, it may help with security. HttpOnly should really be default unless explicitly intended for JavaScript access.

Third, some mobile devices currently do not support cookies.

I do not suggest that Cookie should be avoided completely. I do understand that some cookies are a must,like session cookies. What is the benefit of Cookie over server side storage for non session cookies？

Comment: You can access cookies with JavaScript.

Comment: @Cthulhu As I have stated, "I do understand that some cookies are a must,like session cookies.“

Comment: @Blender That's a pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Blender mentionned, you can access cookie in javascript, on the client side. This is huge, as it means you can make some computation completely on the client side, saving bandwitdh and server load.

In your first point, you mention saving bandwitdh : that's exactly what cookie can achieve, if you perform your task on the client side vs on the server side. Basically, if you can use your users' computing power, that's smarter than your server's (plus you reduce latency and increase user experience).